# Mylyn - passwords storing

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

how Eclipse stores passowrds to Bugzilla (via Mylyn) etc? I have looked for prefs file which  contain password but I didn't found antyhing suitable. I have also checked \.metadata\.mylyn directory.

Could someone give me a tip? I'll be very glad.
Greetings,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your Eclipse related authentication credentials are stored in the Eclipse secure storage. Use Windows -> Preferences -> General Security -> Secure Storage -> Contents to see the stored values.